# React beginner using useState and useEffect to rotate an array every second, and reflect the changes in the DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem while rendering back to the DOM the changes happening inside the useEffect. In console.log the array updates every second, and the items are shifting as I want them to. [image]

But, they are not rendering dynamically back to the DOM. How can I achieve that?
My code:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Main.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

const App = () => {
  let [myList, setMyList] = useState([]);
  myList = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
  const Search = () => (
    <div className="search__input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search Band" />
    </div>
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
    setInterval(() => {
      myList.push(myList.shift());
      console.log((myList));
    }, 1000);
  }
  , [myList]);



  return (
    <div className="main">
      <Search />
      <ul className="main__list">
        {myList.map((item, index) => (
          <div className="main__list__item" key={index}>
            {item}
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the result that I wanted eventually.
My resolve below:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [list, myList] = useState(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      myList(list.slice(1).concat(list[0]));
    }
    , 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  });
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const renderList = () => {
    return list.map((item, index) => {
      return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
    });
  };

  const InputField = () => {
    return (
      <div className="search__input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <InputField />
      <ul className="main__list">{renderList()}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```